# re-frame: nvd3 graph doesn't respond to when its component's subscriptions are updated

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

I'm using the `re-frame` cljs framework which uses `reagent` as its view library. I have an `nvd3` graph component that I want to be updated when its subscriptions update.

Unfortunately, the graph never updates itself after the initial call to `:component-did-mount`. `:component-will-update` is never called again after the intial render.

I want the graph to update itself as the subscription notifies the components of the dat it's listening to being changed.

Here's the graph-container component:

```
(defn weight-graph-container
  []
  (let [weight  (subscribe [:weight-change])
        bodyfat (subscribe [:bodyfat-change])
        weight-amount (reaction (get @weight :amount))
        weight-unit   (reaction (get @weight :unit))
        bf-percentage (reaction (get @bodyfat :percentage))
        lbm           (reaction (lib/lbm @weight-amount @bf-percentage))
        fat-mass      (reaction (- @weight-amount @lbm))]
    (reagent/create-class {:reagent-render weight-graph
                           :component-did-mount (draw-weight-graph @lbm @fat-mass "lb")
                           :display-name "weight-graph"
                           :component-did-update (draw-weight-graph @lbm @fat-mass "lb")})))
```

Here's the graph component:

```
(defn draw-weight-graph [lbm fat-mass unit]
  (.addGraph js/nv (fn []
                     (let [chart (.. js/nv -models pieChart
                                     (x #(.-label %))
                                     (y #(.-value %))
                                     (showLabels true))]
                       (let [weight-data [{:label "LBM" :value lbm} {:label "Fat Mass" :value fat-mass}]]
                         (.. js/d3 (select "#weight-graph svg")
                                   (datum (clj->js weight-data))
                                   (call chart)))))))
```

Finally, here's the component that the graph renders into:

```
(defn weight-graph []
  [:section#weight-graph
   [:svg]])
```

What am I missing? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code solves your problem:

```clj
(defn draw-weight-graph
  [d]
  (let [[lbm fat-mass unit] (reagent/children d)]
    (.addGraph js/nv (fn []
                       (let [chart (.. js/nv -models pieChart
                                       (x #(.-label %))
                                       (y #(.-value %))
                                       (showLabels true))]
                         (let [weight-data [{:label "LBM" :value lbm} {:label "Fat Mass" :value fat-mass}]]
                           (.. js/d3 (select "#weight-graph svg")
                               (datum (clj->js weight-data))
                               (call chart))))))))

(def graph-component (reagent/create-class {:reagent-render weight-graph
                                            :component-did-mount draw-weight-graph
                                            :display-name "weight-graph"
                                            :component-did-update draw-weight-graph}))

(defn weight-graph-container
  []
  (let [weight  (subscribe [:weight-change])
        bodyfat (subscribe [:bodyfat-change])
        weight-amount (reaction (get @weight :amount))
        weight-unit   (reaction (get @weight :unit))
        bf-percentage (reaction (get @bodyfat :percentage))
        lbm           (reaction (lib/lbm @weight-amount @bf-percentage))
        fat-mass      (reaction (- @weight-amount @lbm))]
  (fn []
     [graph-component @lbm @fat-mass "lb"])))
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed the code to `:component-did-update`.